# I'm tasty? Yes and no

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I'm known to be the creamy circle,
> but no, I’m not a cream cheese bagel.
>
> I'm so shy that I might be gone,
> the moment that you turn the lights on.
>
> In the ocean's reflection I will hide,
> Or high up above in the sky.
>
> Now if you say I'm the moon,
> It's unfortunate you spoke too soon.
>
> It's funny how the moon is stuck in your head,
> the same way it prevents my beauty shed.
>
> If you do see me out of the blue,
> Please, don't call the police again, I beg you!

Comment: Does the whole riddle need to be preformatted? It's quite hard to read for me on a mobile device, and I suspect other non-PC platforms will have similar difficulties.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you...

> The Milky Way?

*I'm known to be the creamy circle,

but no, I’m not a cream cheese bagel.*

> White band around the night sky

*I'm so shy that I might be gone,

the moment that you turn the lights on.*

> Would easily disappear with other light

*In the ocean's reflection I will hide,

Or high up above in the sky.*

> *possibly* could be reflected by the ocean, but it is certainly high in the sky

*Now if you say I'm the moon,

It's unfortunate you spoke too soon.*

> Yep. Not the moon!

*It's funny how the moon is stuck in your head,

the same way it prevents my beauty shed.*

> A bright moon can obscure the Milky Way

*If you do see me out of the blue,

Please, don't call the police again, I beg you!*

> A reference to a 1994 blackout where residents called police upon first sightings of the Milky Way. [Found Here](https://timeline.com/los-angeles-light-pollution-ebd60d5acd43)

*Title fits in...*

> Milky Way candy bars are tasty, whereas our galaxy... not so much

Comment: Nice and fast!  For ref Milky way is a translation of the Latin via lactea, from the Greek γαλαξίας κύκλος (galaxías kýklos, "milky circle"), thus "creamy circle"